# Inconsistent Font size and padding ,margin on one page to other page

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the Home page navigation bar, font size and padding are different compared to other pages, but I used the same font size and padding throughout the website [Other pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA6AA.png), [Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwmFB.png) .

Comment: Cheers to the one that can debug an image. How about adding some code?

Comment: Maybe it's not the padding, maybe simply different ```font-family``` use on both those images?

Comment: I have multiple CSS files external and internal so unable to paste the code here, I am new to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

try this in above your css.

```
*{
  font-family:Arial:
  font-size:1.2rem;
}
```

Are you using specific module or library for css?

Comment: i am using module css